# Periodically Refreshing a DataGrid C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, timer, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in C# `WPF` that is filled with `Employees`. Essentially I need to read from a `Database` periodically as when the `Employees` enter a building, a field is modified. I am having a few issues with the best way to approach this situation. First, this is how I define my `DataGrid`;

```
public ICollectionView FilteredView { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> Employees {get; set; }

private void OnPageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _employeeDataService = new EmployeeDataService();
    Employees = _employeeDataService.HandleEmployeeSelect();
    FilteredView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Employees);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = FilteredView;
    DataContext = this;

    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

Essentially the `TimerTick` method that currently fires every second simply calls this method again, so that the entire table is retrieved from the database and the appropriate fields (whether the user is in the building or not is updated).

This method as I said has a number of issues. Firstly, it doesn't look good. As the `DataGrid` is constantly refreshing, any actions that the user takes on the grid is slow and the highlighting of each row is distorted.

Secondly I use methods to filter the `DataGrid`. The user is able to type in a name of an `Employee` and the `DataGrid` is filtered accordingly. Once again because the `DataGrid` is refreshed every second, it is literally impossible to filter on the `DataGrid` because everything the user types is undone every second.

I understand I could potentially refresh the `DataGrid` say every minute which would be much improved, however it is still no where near ideal and I am sure there is a better solution. How can I improve this solution so that the updating of the `DataGrid` is a lot more subtle and unknown to the user?

Comment: Question : Why do you have to refresh the DataGrid frequently? 
And are you just updating the property or re-setting the datacontext for the view every second?

Comment: My suggestion is that you can't fetch all data from database. First check if any changed happened in database. if that function got true than only fetch data from database. (use thread for fetching data)

Comment: @VivekSaurav it's basically a monitoring system of when employees enter / leave a building. At the moment I'm resetting the datacontext but I guess the aim is to avoid that

Comment: @JobyJames "First check if any changed happened in database." How would be a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the whole collection, only add, move or remove items from the `ObservableCollection` that are actually different or changed. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` which will notify the DataGrid.

Comment: How about updating an `Employee` in the `ObservableCollection`, would it work the same way?

Comment: If your `Employee` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the columns in the view are selected using data-binding, then yes. If a value of a column has changed just call the event from the interface with the name of the property. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx.